# Body parameters are not available in node js program though using app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

Tags: node.js

I have created CURD  program in node.js using  MVC design patter and created model, router and controller. By using Postman, POST method I have sent key, value parir .  trying to  create a new record in the mongo data base

Problem: POST key:value are not parsed in node.js controller though i have used body-parser

I have set up the node environment in my laptop and is a stable environment. I have printed the request object in the program using console.log that printed lot of values but empty body:{} value

```
    // Controller pgm

    const Product = require('../models/product.model');
     exports.product_create = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    let product = new Product(
    {
        **name: req.body.name,  (NOT POPULATING FROM BODY)
        price: req.body.price  (NOT POPULATING FROM BODY**)
      }
      );
```

/ below is portion of the server Program in separate file //

```
       const express = require('express');
       const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
       const product = require('./routes/product.route'); // Imports 
      routes  for the products
      const app = express();
```

//configure application

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use('/products', product);
```

//   below is small portion of the Router Program in separate file //

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();



 let ProductSchema = new Schema({
 name: {type: String},
 price: {type: Number},
 });


 // Export the model

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Comment: can you show your postman request? Also can you show your complete import and how you've mounted, not clear from what you've currently posted

Comment: thanks for asking, its resolved I was not properly sending parms in POSTman.

Answer (score 0):

selecting raw and Jason in postman resolved my issue